# Find list of pin codes within given radius from marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I need to retrieve pin codes (Zip Codes) from a given radius using google maps api. Is it possible?

I have researched quite a bit online but cant seem to find relevant answers. I am able to draw the radius but cannot figure how to retrieve pin codes (Zip Codes) from that radius

```
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
      map:map,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      radius: 5000,
    });
    circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');
```

Comment: Where do the pin codes exist? How does this relate to PHP?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the pin codes from the radius drawn on google maps. I don't know if this is even possible to do, hence asking. Tagged PHP just in case it is required.

Comment: You can do it.  You just need a source of the pin code locations (or polygons), depending on the country, that might be freely available.

Answer (score -1):

Google maps has an api for "address lookup" based on a specific location. Take a look at [Reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse). But this api is expensive @$5 per 1000 lookups and you have no idea where to probe. If you are looking for zip code regions then you can buy these areas online for example [US zip codes database](https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database/) but its expensive. A more important question is what are you trying to do with your code? What are you going to do with the zipcodes when you get them from your `Circle` 10km in diameter?

Comment: Hello Steve, Thanks for your answer. I want to locate zip codes in the given radius so that I can target addresses in my database with them. I intend on using this for lost pets.